How should you handle questions formed with "flags" like (HELP!!!) (CRISIS!!) etc?
Some questions have additional flags that do not really contribute information. 
Many times due to loss of funds. How should these questions be handled?

If they are legitimate, original questions we should answer them.  However, those "flag" words should be edited out of the title and body of the question.  New users don't realize that they only distract from the question they are asking.
Most of these questions, however, tend to be duplicates of our canonical questions.  In this case, marking them as a duplicate should be the best course of action.  It wouldn't hurt to edit out all the flag terms in this case too, since the question may differ slightly from the suggested duplicate, and may not be closed.

+1 and added a link to our collection of canonical questions
